# Simple Java lottery simulator using math.random and while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

How would i format a while loop to check for duplicates and if there is a duplicate, to not return that number(s)?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotterySimulator 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      final int POOL1 = 68;
      final int POOL2 = 25;

      long ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4, ball5, pball;

      ball1 = Math.round(POOL1*Math.random()) + 1;
      ball2 = Math.round(POOL1*Math.random()) + 1;
      ball3 = Math.round(POOL1*Math.random()) + 1;
      ball4 = Math.round(POOL1*Math.random()) + 1;
      ball5 = Math.round(POOL1*Math.random()) + 1;
      pball = Math.round(POOL2*Math.random()) + 1;
```

Comment: Depends on what it is you are trying to avoid duplicating.  And you might not even need a `while` loop.

Comment: I want to avoid duplicates on the first 5 numbers (ball1, ball2... ball5) and yes i am supposed to use a while loop for the problem but cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Instead of having individual `int` variables `ball1`,`ball2`, etc., try putting the numbers in an `int` array `int[] balls` so you can easily iterate over them to check for duplicates.  Keep track of how many balls you've successfully drawn and each time you pick a new random number, search over the previously drawn balls to make sure the new one isn't a dupe.  The `while` loop will go until you successfully draw 5 unique numbers.

Comment: for purposes of my class i cannot use an array either as we have not reached that point. So, im trying to find a way to check each variable against each variable for duplicates if that makes sense. thank you for your help

Comment: You can ensure five unique balls by checking that each ball is different from all the lower-numbered ones;  i.e. `ball2 != ball1`, `ball3 != ball2 && ball3 != ball1`, etc.  You could draw and test all five at once in one big loop, or draw and test balls 2 thru 5 individually in four smaller loops, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set collection to store unique values. Method `add()`
 return `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element

For example:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int POOL1 = 68;
        final int POOL2 = 25;

        int i = 0;
        Set<Long> ballSet = new HashSet<>();
        while (i < 5) {
           long ball = Math.round(POOL1 * Math.random()) + 1;

           if (!ballSet.add(ball)) {
               continue;
           };
           i++;
        }
        long pball = Math.round(POOL2 * Math.random()) + 1;
        while (ballSet.contains(pball)) {
            pball = Math.round(POOL2 * Math.random()) + 1;
        }
        String winner = ballSet.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(", "));
        System.out.println("Your winning numbers are: " + winner);
        System.out.printf(" and the powerball is: %d", pball);
    }
 }
```

Comment: LotterySimulator.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        Set<Long> ballSet = new HashSet<>();
        ^
  symbol:   class Set
  location: class LotterySimulator
LotterySimulator.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        Set<Long> ballSet = new HashSet<>();
                                ^
  symbol:   class HashSet
  location: class LotterySimulator
2 errors
any ideas?

Comment: import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

Comment: When i compile my program now, i get no error. However, I also get no output. I must have "System.out.printf("Your winning numbers are: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4, ball5); 
      System.out.printf(" and the powerball is: %d", pball);"

Comment: I appreciate your help. However the set and haset util's cause errors as my class has not covered those topics yet. I understand if you cant/dont want to do the program without those, but thank you